# Replacing generic exceptions with more specific exception types?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, runtimeexception, unchecked-exception

For a project I've been working on, we have some blocks that look like this:

Class A:

```
try {
   callSomeMethod();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   throw new SomeCustomExceptionTypeForMetrics("");
}
```

However, I was tasked with replacing all instances where we catch generic exceptions with only specific "expected" types of exceptions.

The problem is callSomeMethod() has something like this

Class B:

```
try {
    if (someCondition...) {

    }
    else {
       //failed
       throw new RuntimeException("Timeout while waiting for results")
    }
}
catch(InterruptedException e) {
   // do some failure stuff here
   throw new RuntimeException("Something here");
}
```

Ideally, my group has asked me to change as *little* as possible, and I can't change the signature for callSomeMethod(), but they also don't want to just catch any RuntimeException in Class A since they don't want to catch just any type of RuntimeException - only the ones we're excepting from Class B.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Change those `RuntimeExeption`s to something more specific. Create custom classes if needed.

Comment: Did I Understand this correct: You are supposed to catch RuntimeExceptions but only if they explicitly got thrown in class B in the java code with "throw new RuntimeException()" while ignoring those that might come from somewhere else?

Comment: Is modifying class B an option?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 
To answer 911DidBush and slambeth: 
* Basically, if any other exception is thrown besides the ones we expect (InterruptedException or if we throw one as a result of the if condition), we shouldn't catch it in Class A. 
* Class B can be modified, but the signature can't be

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your `callSomeMethod`'s signature contains `throws Exception`, and you can't change it: Change the `RuntimeException`s in the method to a custom `Exception` class, and then in Class A:

```
try {
   callSomeMethod();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   if(e instanceof CustomException)
       //Log it or something, for metrics?
}
```

This is kind of silly, but might be necessary if you can't change the method signature. (If you can change it, you could catch the `CustomException` directly.) You could even make a method in your logger that takes an `Exception`, checks what type it is, and acts accordingly. Then just use this method in every catch statement that you need to edit.

While designing this solution, keep in mind that `RuntimeException`s don't need to be caught. It could save you some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you chnage your code in class B as below

```
try {
        if (someCondition...) {

        }
        else {
           //failed
           throw new MyRuntimeException("Timeout while waiting for results")
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
       // do some failure stuff here
       throw new MyRuntimeException("Something here");
    }
```

and define MyRuntimeException as :

```
class MyRuntimeException extends RuntimeException{
..
}
```

In class A, you only need to catch MyRuntimeException exception .

Hope this solve your problem!!